# Getting YouTube video data using PHP

Tags: wordpress

I've been searching Google for how to get the title from a video using PHP and I found this:

```
$video_id = 'y8Kyi0WNg40';
$content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . $video_id);
parse_str($content, $ytarr);
echo $ytarr['title'];
```

I am using the Gravity Forms plugin for Wordpress and I tried to implement this:
(This code should automatically get the video ID from a YouTube URL and with that ID get the title. Getting the ID works, title doesn't)

```
add_filter("gform_save_field_value", "save_field_value", 10, 4);
function save_field_value($value, $lead, $field, $form){
global $id;

//if not the form with fields to encode, just return the unaltered value without checking the fields
if(absint($form["id"]) <> 1) {
    return $value;
}

//array of field ids to encode
$encode_fields = array(2,7);

parse_str( parse_url( $value, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
$id = $my_array_of_vars['v'];

$content = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$id);;
parse_str($content, $ytarr);
$title = $ytarr['title'];

//see if the current field id is in the array of fields to encode; encode if so, otherwise return unaltered value
if(in_array($field["id"],$encode_fields)) {
    if(absint($field["id"]) == 2) {
        return $id;
    }
    elseif(absint($field["id"]) == 7) {
        return $videoTitle;
    }
} else {
    return $value;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Hope someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for getting youtube title if u are having video id.

```
<?
    $vidID = $_POST['vidID'];
    $url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $vidID;
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->load($url);
    $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Video Name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" value="ID Here" name="vidID" />
            <input type="submit" value="Get Name" />
        </form>
        <div id="page">URL: [<?= $url ?>]</div>
        <div id="title">Title: [<?= $title ?>]</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this now. Do you also know how to get the description and author of the video?

Comment: I tried this to dynamically populate the title field in the form, using your code, but it doesn't work, it just gives no title at all ($id is the video ID which I got from another function): 

`add_filter('gform_field_value_get_title','my_custom_population_function');
function my_custom_population_function($value){
 global $id;
     $url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $id;
     $doc = new DOMDocument;
     $doc->load($url);
     $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
 return $title;
}`

Comment: you are getting the info in xml format so you can simple use this code for getting title either you convert your data in json format and then use json_decode function                              $xmlInfoVideo    = simplexml_load_file("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$videoId."?v=2&fields=title");

foreach($xmlInfoVideo->children() as $title) { $videoTitle = strtoupper((string) $title); }

Comment: Actually, your code works. However, I can't seem to get the title in the actual title field. I tried returning $title to the video ID field (to test) and it actually worked. Somehow I can't return it to the title field.

I have this in my code, an array of field IDs that need to be populated automatically: $encode_fields = array(2,7); (2 being field ID of the video ID and 7 of the title)
but at the end of the function I have return $id. (Where do I put $title though?) Is it possible to return an array where the first element is the video ID and the second the title?

Comment: you can return it using a key value pair array eg:-                     return array('videoid','title') from your function and using list('$videoid','title')=getData();    echo $videoid." = ".$title; wheever you want to use this values

Comment: glad you got the title of your youtube video https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?#youtube_data_api_tag_title from this link you will get all your answers... be sure to mark this as the accepted answer and vote it up then, that way it'll help someone else in case they don't read the comments

Comment: Thank you very much for the help so far! But I still can't get it to work :/ Please check my answer for the code I have so far.

Comment: simply use this return array("key" => "value"); key means video id and value means title in your case array is like return array($videoid=>$title);

Comment: I think that the problem is with returning the result. Somehow it is not working. I could do 2 seperate functions for the video ID and title, but somehow the video ID is not being used properly or not at all in the title function...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got so far:

```
add_filter("gform_save_field_value", "save_field_value", 10, 4);
function save_field_value($value, $lead, $field, $form){
    global $videoid;

    //if not the form with fields to encode, just return the unaltered value without checking the fields
    if(absint($form["id"]) <> 1)
            return $value;

    //array of field ids to encode
    $encode_fields = array(2,7);

    parse_str( parse_url( $value, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
    $videoid = $my_array_of_vars['v'];

    $url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$videoid;
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->load($url);
    $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    //see if the current field id is in the array of fields to encode; encode if so, otherwise return unaltered value
    if(in_array($field["id"],$encode_fields))
            return array('videoid','title');
    else
            return $value;
}
```